# Асинхронный запрос к серверу

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, async-await

Я использую функцию Request для связи клиента с сервером. 
    string result = settingsWindows.Request(settingsView.Address + ":" + settingsView.Port.ToString() + "/Users/ReturnUsers", "");

```
public string Request(string connectionString, string param)
        {
            string res = "";
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://" + connectionString);
                request.Method = "POST"; // для отправки используется метод Post
                                         // данные для отправки
                string data = param;
                // преобразуем данные в массив байтов
                byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                // устанавливаем тип содержимого - параметр ContentType
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Устанавливаем заголовок Content-Length запроса - свойство ContentLength
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                //записываем данные в поток запроса
                using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        res = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                response.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                res = "ERROR";
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Эта функция возвращает результат запроса. Когда адрес сервера указан верно, то все хорошо. Но когда неверно - то основной поток блокируется на строках

```
using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
       dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

после чего вылетает исключение. Я бы хотел как-то асинхронно выполнять данную функцию. Не до конца разобрался с async/await. Попробовал сделать

```
public async Task<string> Request(string connectionString, string param)
{
   ...
   using (Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
   {
         dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
   }
   ...
}
```

но так вообще процесс блокируется намертво. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно еще попробовать?

Comment: Я бы на твоем месте поискал бы какой ню-гет с более высокоуровневыми методами. Какой-нибудь REST нюгет.... Это бы сильно упростило бы код и обучение.

Answer (score 0):

Цель в принципе разобраться как сделать запрос или как сделать его асинхронным или как сделать асинхронный запрос именно с WebRequest?

Если нужно просто сделать асинхронный, то вот работающий код:

```
public async Task<CallResult> PutAsync<TRequest>(string url, TRequest request)
        {
            string reqJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request); // user your XML serializer here instead
            var reqContent = new StringContent(reqJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); // and here use XML
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaTypeApplicationJson);                    
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(url, reqContent);

                string message;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode || response.Content == null)
                {
                    message = response.ReasonPhrase;
                }
                else
                {
                    string unparsedResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // handle error after it...

                }
                return new CallResult
                {
                    IsSuccessful = response.IsSuccessStatusCode,
                    Message = message,
                };
            }
        }
```

можно ещё упростить для строк:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage > PostAsync(string url, string request)
            {
                var reqContent = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"); // and here use XML
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                  mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml");
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaType);                    
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, reqContent);


                }
            }
```

Сделать его синхронным легко - убери async, await и вызови нужный метод client

Только учти, результатом работы метода не должен быть код ошибки. Если там ошибка, то бросай исключение. Если ошибка ожидаемая, то делай объект в который скажет что запрос не прошёл. Но не код ошибки в перемешку с валидными данными чтобы потом проверять if(result == "ERROR") { handle it }
В случае с низкоуровневыми библиотеками (типа запросов) вообще нельзя подавлять исключения, только логгировать.

Comment: Мне нужно отправлять именно POST-запрос. А в HttpClient есть только PostAsync. Не подскажите, как реализовать это синхронным методом?

Comment: Сначала вы пишите: Я бы хотел как-то асинхронно выполнять данную функцию.
PostAsync - и есть асинхронный пост запрос. 
Потом вы пишите, что хотите просто отравить POST запрос. Вы имеете ввиду синхронный Post? потому что PostAsync  и есть POST запрос.

var request = PostAsync(....).Result; это всё что вам нужно, чтобы в синхронном коде вызвать асинхронный запрос. Вопрос в том, нужно ли вам это на самом деле.